# Vehicle tracking by QGIS

Tags: qgis, gps

I need to do routing for a vehicle. A map with detailed turn-by-turn driving directions should be generated. For example, it should be like car race game in which the map with vehicle tracking is provided and driving instructions are shown by arrow keys. Is it possible with QGIS?

EDIT:

QGIS gps tracking plugin is useful to track vehicle. Please, can anyone clearly explain how I can provide driving direction to the driver (for example: turn left, turn right for given start point and end point).

Comment: I'm not sure that there is any plugin readily available now that can do this. Are you willing to do some programming?

Comment: yes @dassouki. In QGIS how can i do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this http://project-osrm.org/. Their api return json with turn by turn instructions in the format

["instruction","streetname",length,position,time,"length","earth_direction",azimuth]

Example: ["Turn left","High Street",200,4,10,"200m","NE",22.5]

For more info https://github.com/DennisOSRM/Project-OSRM/wiki/_pages

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the Road Graph Plugin available in Quantum Gis 1.9. QuantumGIS 1.9 it has not been officially released yet. but you can get it from http://qgis.org/downloads/weekly/

UPDATE:

QGIS 2.0 has been released.

Comment: hi byom, road graph plugin is already available in QGIS 1.8. so can you tell me what is new about that plugin in QGIS 1.9.